# Jquery.Ajax does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to write a Jquery. Ajax in codeigniter. But it does not post the content  instead all the page is loading from the start  when I click links.So all the starting animation is shown again.
My ajax.js is inside header.php head section :

```
$("#sidebar-content ul li a").click( function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var target_url = $(this).attr('href');
   $.ajax({
       url: target_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: target_url,
   success: function(response) {
                $('#content').html(response.msg);
            }
   });
return false;
});
```

Menu.php file is :

```
<!-- SIDEBAR -->

<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar-content">
            <!-- MENU -->
       <ul id="menu">
         <li class="current"><a href="<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>">ANASAYFA</a></li>
         <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
```

I want only content division change in the main page. How can i correct  the code?

edit 1:

This works now . But I hade to use #page instead of #content.

```
$("#sidebar-content ul li a").click( function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#page').load(this.href);
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Why are you using the URL in the `data` field? You just want to load the response in `#content`?

Comment: yes I want only the data in the content field. What must I do ?

Comment: what is the point in sending the `target_url` as the data?

Comment: Have you tried `e.stopPropagation();`? It maybe that click on a link bubbles up and document reloads since its normal behaviour when you click a link.

Comment: is your code in some `$(document).load(function(){...});`?

Comment: What must be the data field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should have to put `return false` at the end of `click` event -

```
$("#sidebar-content ul li a").click( function(e){
     // your existing stuff here

     return false; // or e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the complete code try this

```
$("#sidebar-content ul li a").click( function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#content').load(this.href);
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was my first thought when I read the question. This should fix it. Provided, there's nothing else weird happening on click.

Comment: Yes there is return false over there .. It is in the end?

Comment: okay i examined your code and what i found that you are using target_url in "url" and "data" field. Why did you do that?

Comment: Yes it works , but when i click links , the content started to move to the right ?I mean the view file content moves 80px right?

Comment: There must be some CSS related issue. You should have to check the css of the container div. Mark me as an answer if this will fix your problem

Comment: I solved it by changing from content to page. It works fluently thank you .

Answer (score 0):

To load some code in a container, you just need to use the load method.
Something like:

```
$( "#content" ).load( "your url here" );
```

Take a look in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Remove the "a" tag and use a span for example. It will not trigger the hyperlink and you will not to stop propagation. Instead of "a" use:

```
<span data-url="your url...">link</span>
```

And you will get the "data-url" attribute when you click the span to do the load.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

Make sure you link jquery like;

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
```

or

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
```

and wrap your javascript inside;

```
$(document).ready( function() {

});
```

inside the  portion of your web page to make your code run.

```
$('#content').text(response.msg);
```

instead of

```
$('#content').html(response.msg);
```